# Accessing parent module function from child module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am importing a module (say A.py ) in my main.py
Function `getJobDetails` is defined in main.py and is being called from a function in A.py as well.
However, A.py doesn't seem to have access to `getJobDetails` which is defined in main.py

From what I understand, A.py code gets added to namespace for main.py and should have access to all functions defined in main.py

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, why do you think it should? You're importing A into main, not the other way round.

Comment: Don't import statements work like a #include in C? I thought if the A.py code gets pasted inside of main, and the control flow is with main.py then A.py would have had access to main.py functions.

Comment: No, not at all. Separate namespaces remain separate.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the below to the top of A.py

```py
from main import getJobDetails
```

I hope this helps / works.

Comment: Nope, not working. 
Please note I am importing A.py in main as ```from A.py import functionName``` where functionName is the only function defined inside of A.py

Comment: Log

```File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from resources import getResourceDetails,setResources
  File "/Users/kkohli/Desktop/Dev/Python Scripts/Selenium Automation/Craft/src/resources.py", line 9, in <module>
    from main import getJobDetails,postRequest
  File "/Users/kkohli/Desktop/Dev/Python Scripts/Selenium Automation/Craft/src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from resources import getResourceDetails,setResources
ImportError: cannot import name 'getResourceDetails' from 'resources' (/Users/kkohli/Desktop/Dev/Python Scripts/Selenium Automation/Craft/src/resources.py)```